# Ruby on Rails: wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting strange error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)):
```

On this line:

```
<%= (!attach.file_size.nil?) ? "(#{number_to_human_size(attach.file_size.to_i).to_s})": ""  %>
```

Here's my code:

```
<% if !pr.attachments.empty? %>
<ul class="attached_files">
  <% pr.attachments.each do |attach| %>
    <li><a href="<%= attach.path_url%> " target="_blank"><%= attach.path_identifier%></a> 
    <%= (!attach.file_size.nil?) ? "(#{number_to_human_size(attach.file_size.to_i).to_s})": ""  %>
    </li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I don't get where problem is. Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What locale?  If not an English locale, try one.

Sounds a lot like [this bug](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues/183), in which a call to `number_to_human_size` eventually called `BigDecimal.new(the_number.to_s).round(...).to_f`, and the `round()`ing failed because of a locale issue.  The exception generated exactly matches your error (*"wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)"*).

Comment: I use English locale & config.i18n.fallbacks set to true so there mustn't be any problems with missing traslation

Comment: @AlphaB, can we see a full stack trace?

Comment: You were right. It was a problem with missing translations (backend part is using Ru locale) so i added missing translation and problem disappeared. Thanks a lot !